# Getting error "Message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL" but never used GET anywhere

Tags: java, servlets

web.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">

<servlet>
 <servlet-name>adding</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.nokia.web.servlet.practice.AddServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>adding</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 Hello World
 <form action="add" method="post">
  Enter 1st number : <input type="text" name="num1">
  Enter 2nd number : <input type="text" name="num2">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

AddServlet.java file:

```html
package com.nokia.web.servlet.practice;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet{

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
  int i = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
  int j = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));

  
  PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
  out.println(" post sum = "+ (i+j));
  
 }

 

}
```

and the error is

```css
HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
Type Status Report

Message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.
```

Kindly give some suggestions how to make it work.
......................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What is the url that you are invoking to display the input form? And also, are you getting this error before or after submit?

Comment: url which is run first while running the index.hml file: http://localhost:8085/WebProjectYutb/index.html 
url after pressing submit : http://localhost:8085/WebProjectYutb/add?num1=11&num2=11
Getting error after submit

Comment: Can it possibly be because you are missing `@Override` annotation on the `doPost` method?

Comment: You can also use your browser's development tools to check which requests are really made.

Comment: i tried with @Override ... its not working

Comment: @vanje: i printed req.getMethod()... it is always taking GET no matter what i am putting in method="...." in index.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to URL localhost:8085/WebProjectYutb/add?num1=11&num2=11 after submitted that means it is using GET method because POST method does not show parameters at URL.
Since you did not implemented GET method you are receiving HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed.

You can fix the problem by overriding doGet Method and forwarding request to doPost like below:

```
package com.nokia.web.servlet.practice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7041461467204399253L;

    public AddServlet() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
        int j = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println(" post sum = " + (i + j));

    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this way as well... then also the url is showing parameters. Now how to hide parameters from url?

Comment: Can you View-Page-Source of your index.html on browser and send to check it. Which server did you deployed application? Is there any javascript before submitting form request?

Comment: Thank you all... I dont know what actually worked... but its working now. I added @Override to doPost() and also added try catch block inside doPost... and its working.